# Rx{Type} vs Rx<Type> vs .obs in GetX state management library of Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, observable, reactive-programming, flutter-getx

Per [the documentation](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/state_management.md#declaring-a-reactive-variable):

> You have 3 ways to turn a variable into an "observable".
>
> 1. The first is using `Rx{Type}`.
>
>    ```
>    // initial value is recommended, but not mandatory
>    final name = RxString('');
>    ...
>    ```
> 2. The second is to use `Rx` and use Darts Generics, `Rx<Type>`
>
>    ```
>    final name = Rx<String>('');
>    ...
>
>    // Custom classes - it can be any class, literally
>    final user = Rx<User>();
>    ```
> 3. The third, more practical, easier and preferred approach, just add `.obs` as a property of your `value`:
>
>    ```
>    final name = ''.obs;
>    ...
>    ```

How do I decide which method of using observables should be followed in which situation?
Do they all result in exactly same behaviour and only differ by syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three approaches to using observables in the GetX state management library of Flutter—Rx{Type}, Rx, and .obs—essentially achieve the same behavior of making a variable observable. The difference lies in the syntax and convenience they offer.

**1. Rx{Type}:**
Using the Rx{Type} syntax allows you to create an observable variable without specifying an initial value. However, it is recommended to provide an initial value to the observable for better type inference and improved performance.

Example:
dart

```
final name = RxString('');
```

**2. Rx:**
Using Rx syntax involves using Dart's generics to specify the type of the observable variable. This approach is useful when dealing with custom classes or more complex data types.

Example:
dart

```
final name = Rx<String>('');
final user = Rx<User>();
```

**3. .obs:**
The .obs syntax is a shorthand and the preferred approach in GetX. It allows you to mark a value as observable by simply adding .obs as a property to the value. This approach is more concise and easier to use, especially when dealing with basic data types like strings, numbers, and booleans.

Example: Dart

```
final name = ''.obs;
```

**All three methods result in the same behavior of creating an observable variable that can be used within the GetX state management framework.**
The choice between them mainly depends on personal preference, code readability, and the complexity of the data types you're working with.

In general, the .obs syntax is recommended as the preferred approach due to its simplicity and ease of use. It is suitable for most scenarios, especially when dealing with basic data types. If you have custom classes or more complex data structures, using Rx can be more appropriate. However, you can choose any of these approaches based on your specific requirements and coding style.

Comment: Please add citations for your sources.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Answer (score 4):

We use all three in our codebase. 1 and 3 are both just shorthand for 2. We enforce type declaration so our variables tend to be declared as follows:

```
final RxString name = ''.obs;
final Rx<User> user = myUser.obs;
```

OR more likely (if they are nullable - the n here signifies nullable)

```
final RxnString name = RxnString();
final Rxn<User> user = Rxn<User>();
```

This is our preferred approach. However, if you want to stick to a single syntax I would recommend using option 2 as it will work in all cases. It may just be a bit more clunky to read. Note that it will require you to pass in a value in this format. Only Rxn doesn't require an initial value.

```
final Rx<String> name = Rx<String>('');
final Rx<User?> user = Rx<User?>(null);
```

Answer (score -1):

In GetX Flutter, there are three syntax options for declaring observable variables. However, these options do not impact the variable's behavior; they only differ in syntax.